# Why does the HTML Drag and Drop dataTransfer become an object inside of iframe

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I'm testing some code for a web builder. Using DnD API I want to be able to drag an Element into an iframe. However, when dropping the element, using `e.target.appendChild()` I get an error saying that the parameter supplied is not an Element. Using `e.target.append()`, it drops `[object HTMLDivElement]`.

This is just simple testing code, because I haven't worked with the API much. But I've tried StackOverflow, Google, researching the API, and reading blog posts. Nothing works. I originally had a `window.ondrop` and other events setup in a script loaded inside of the iframe, but ran into the error, so I moved everything into a single script and set the events back up using `document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument.ondrop`. All events except for dragstart are based inside the iframe.

```
const element = document.querySelector('.draggable');
const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
const iframeBody = iframe.contentDocument.querySelector('body');

element.ondragstart = e => {
  console.log('mainWindow: dragstart');
  element.id = 'draggable';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', e.target);
  console.log(element);
  console.log(e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html'));

  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
};

iframe.contentWindow.ondragenter = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  iframeBody.style.transition = '0.5s';
  iframeBody.style.opacity = 0.5;
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
  console.log('contentWindow: dragenter');
  console.log(e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html'));
};

iframe.contentWindow.ondragover = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html'));
};

iframe.contentWindow.ondrop = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('contentWindow: drop');
  const data = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
  console.log(e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html'));

  e.target.appendChild(data);
};

iframe.contentWindow.ondragleave = e => {
  iframeBody.style.opacity = 1;
  console.log('contentWindow: dragleave');
  console.log(e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html'));
};
```

I originally expected it to be a simple drag and drop procedure but, receiving `[object HTMLDivElement]` in both logs and pasting have proven to be a headache. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out, for whatever reason, you have to use `e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.id)` and `e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain')).cloneNode(true))` if your're copying an element, or remove `.cloneNode(true)` if your moving an element.

Here's the updated script, `fallback` is simply a dropzone div alongside the `iframe`, I was testing to make sure it worked for both and not just the parent document.

```
const element = document.querySelector('.draggable');
const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
const iframeBody = iframe.contentDocument.querySelector('body');
const fallback = document.querySelector('.dropzone-fallback');

element.ondragstart = e => {
  console.log('mainWindow: dragstart');
  element.id = 'draggable';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.id);
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
};

iframe.contentWindow.ondragenter = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  iframeBody.style.transition = '0.5s';
  iframeBody.style.opacity = 0.5;
  // e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
  console.log('contentWindow: dragenter');
};

fallback.ondragenter = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
};

iframe.contentWindow.ondragover = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
  console.log(e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
};

fallback.ondragover = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
};

iframe.contentWindow.ondrop = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('contentWindow: drop');
  const data = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
  e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
};

fallback.ondrop = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
  e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
};

iframe.contentWindow.ondragleave = e => {
  iframeBody.style.opacity = 1;
  console.log('contentWindow: dragleave');
};
```